# iText - how to create an AF entry in Document Catalog in a PDF_A_3B - PDF/A-3 B

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have to create a PDF/A-3-B (ISO 19005-3:2012. Part 3) using iText with attachments.

> > How do I create an AF entry in the PDF's Document Catalog?

I've used the Java code at the end of this question to produce a mock test. Using Adobe XI Pro Preflight, I see that the PDF's structure became like that:

> ```
> The document catalog root
>    AF:
>       0: (6)   /T:FileSpec
> ```

But the structure should be:

> ```
> The document catalog root
>    AF:
>       0: (6) [6 0 R]   /T:FileSpec
> ```

In other words, I think the AF entry should be a pointer to the attachment itself.

The ISO say that:

> ```
> KEY:   AF
> TYPE:  array of dictionaries
> Value: (Optional) An array of File Specification Dictionaries 
>        representing the source content from which this document is 
>        derived or data used to produce the visual representation.
> ```

The mock Java code that may be used to produce an example is the following:

```
public static final String RESULT = "target/pdfa3.pdf";
public static final String FONTPATH = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf";
private static Font FONT = FontFactory.getFont(FONTPATH, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

public void test(){
   //creating document
   Document document = new Document();
   PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT), PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3B);

   //creating default Xmp
   writer.createXmpMetadata();

   document.open();

   //adding attachment as embedded file
   PdfDictionary fileParameter = new PdfDictionary();
   fileParameter.put(new PdfName("ModDate"), new PdfString("2013-01-09T16:28-02:00"));
   PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, src.getAbsolutePath(), src.getName(), null, false, "image/jpeg", fileParameter);
   fs.put(new PdfName("AFRelationship"), new PdfName("Source"));
   writer.addFileAttachment(src.getName().substring(0, src.getName().indexOf('.')), fs);

   //???????????????????
   //THIS IS THE POINT: HOW TO ADD AN AF ENTRY?
   //this does not work:
   writer.getExtraCatalog().put(new PdfName("AF"), new PdfArray(fs));
   //???????????????????

   //adding some text
   document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!", FONT));

   //done!
   document.close();
}
```

Comment: You need to be more clear and break your question up to get the best answers on SO. What is your question, what have you tried.

Comment: I've tried what is between "//???" and "//????". My question is: How do I create an AF entry in a PDF's Document Catalog?

Answer (score 0):

You are (or were, many years ago) passing directly the `PdfFileSpecification fs` object to `new PdfArray`.
You should pass a reference to it instead:

```java
writer.getExtraCatalog().put(new PdfName("AF"), 
                             new PdfArray(fs.getReference()));
```

See more complete answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020431/326162