# Creating PDF/A-3: Embedded file shall contain valid Params key

Tags: pdf, itext

im trying to create a PDF/A-3 with itextpdf-5.4.5 and itext-pdfa-5.4.5.
When i set the PdfFileSpecification, i get the following Exception:

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: Embedded file shall contain valid Params key.
```

This is the part where i create the PdfDictionary:

```
PdfDictionary params = new PdfDictionary();
params.put(PdfName.MODDATE, new PdfDate());
PdfFileSpecification fileSpec = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(
writer, "./src/main/resources/com/itextpdf/invoice.xml", "invoice.xml", null, false, "text/xml", params);
```

I found the method where the check happens, but i dont find any solution:

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfA3Checker.checkEmbeddedFile

protected void checkEmbeddedFile(PdfDictionary embeddedFile) {
    PdfDictionary params = getDirectDictionary(embeddedFile.get(PdfName.PARAMS));
    if (params == null) {
        throw new PdfAConformanceException(embeddedFile, MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage("embedded.file.shall.contain.valid.params.key"));
    }
```

Any idea? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: [This article](http://itextsupport.com/download/pdfa3.html) explains how to properly attach files in case of PDF/A-3.

Comment: How is it not working? I used it (admittedly with iText 5.4.4) and it did work.

Comment: thank you, i tried it but this is not working. The order of the  fileEmbedded method in this example is not right in my opinion. My itext version is expecting following order: -writer
-filePath 
-fileDisplay 
-fileStore
-compress
-mimeType
-fileParameter

Comment: There are 5 overloads of that method. Thus, there are multiple correct parameter orders.

Comment: Ok, I re-ran the sample with 5.4.5 and get the same exception. I assume a bug has been introduced between 5.4.4 and 5.4.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In general

PDF/A-3 has some special requirements concerning embedded files, among them

> An embedded file's stream dictionary should contain a **Params** key whose value shall be a dictionary containing at least a **ModDate** key whose value shall be the latest modification date of the source file.
>
> *(Annex E.1 of ISO 19000-3)*

iText support explains on [PDF/A-3 with iText](https://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/pdfa-3-itext) how to create PDF/A-3 compliant PDFs from scratch, and they also demonstrate there how to embed files in a PDF/A-3 compliant manner, their sample code:

```
PdfDictionary parameters = new PdfDictionary();
parameters.put(PdfName.MODDATE, new PdfDate());
PdfFileSpecification fileSpec = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(
    writer, "./src/main/resources/com/itextpdf/invoice.xml",
    "invoice.xml", null, "application/xml", parameters, 0);
fileSpec.put(new PdfName("AFRelationship"), new PdfName("Data"));
writer.addFileAttachment("invoice.xml", fileSpec);
PdfArray array = new PdfArray();
array.add(fileSpec.getReference());
writer.getExtraCatalog().put(new PdfName("AF"), array);
```

This example also adds the associated file entry (**AF**) to the Catalog which is another requirement.

BTW, *strictly speaking* the **Params** dictionary is only required on a *should* base, not *shall*. Thus, this is actually a recommendation and there can be valid PDF/A-3 documents with attachments in the wild which do not have this entry.

As there is no apparent reason why iText would be better off not following this recommendation when creating PDF/A-3 files, though, the strict interpretation by its checks is ok.

### Issue in iText 5.4.5

The check the OP found has been introduced recently. This check already is triggered while storing the file in the PDF file. Unfortunately at this time the params dictionary has not yet been assigned, only a reference has been reserved. Thus, the check fails, even though shortly after the dictionary would have been written.

From `PdfFileSpecification.java`:

```
        stream.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILE);
        stream.flateCompress(compressionLevel);
        PdfDictionary param = new PdfDictionary();
        if (fileParameter != null) {
            param.merge(fileParameter);
        }
        if (!param.contains(PdfName.MODDATE)) {
            param.put(PdfName.MODDATE, new PdfDate());
        }
        if (fileStore != null) {
            param.put(PdfName.SIZE, new PdfNumber(stream.getRawLength()));
            stream.put(PdfName.PARAMS, param);
        }
        else
            stream.put(PdfName.PARAMS, refFileLength);

        if (mimeType != null)
            stream.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName(mimeType));

        ref = writer.addToBody(stream).getIndirectReference();
```

During this operation the check happens (and fails).

```
        if (fileStore == null) {
            stream.writeLength();
            param.put(PdfName.SIZE, new PdfNumber(stream.getRawLength()));
            writer.addToBody(param, refFileLength);
        }
```

And here, directly thereafter, the params would have been written.

### A work-around

`PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded` allows you to present the data as a `byte[]` instead of as a file in the file system. As you can see in the source above the processing differs in that case: `fileStore` contains that `byte[]` argument. If you follow up on the `fileStore` use in there, you'll see that for a non-`null` value of it the params dictionary is written as a direct object and, therefore, present in the test.

Thus, you can use iText 5.4.5 for PDF/A-3 file attachments if you supply the files as `byte[]` instances instead.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i will use 5.4.4 until the bug will be solved :-).

Comment: @user3177193 This issue is fixed. The fix will be available in the next release.

Comment: "Thus, you can use iText 5.4.5 for PDF/A-3 file attachments if you supply the files as byte[] instances instead."

Does anyone have an example of this, I do not see a method that takes a byte[] instead of the Strings for file path and file name in 5.5.8

Comment: @user1567291 *"I do not see a method that takes a byte[] instead of the Strings for file path and file name in 5.5.8"* - all `PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded` have a `byte[] fileStore` parameter which is documented as *the byte array with the file. If it is not `null` it takes precedence over `filePath`*.

Answer (score 0):

If you use iText-5.5.9, you will need to add following additionally:

```
final PdfDictionary extraCatalog = writer.getExtraCatalog();
final PdfDictionary markInfoDict = new PdfDictionary();
markInfoDict.put(PdfName.MARKED, new PdfBoolean(true));
extraCatalog.put(PdfName.MARKINFO, markInfoDict);
```

Otherwise you will get a `PdfAConformanceException`