# iText attaching file to existing PDF/A-3 results in PdfAConformanceException

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfa

I am trying to attach a file to a existing PDF/A-3.

This [example](http://itextsupport.com/download/pdfa3.html) explains how to create a PDF/A-3  and attach content to it.

My next step was to adapt the code and use the PdfAStamper instead of the document.

So here is my resulting code.

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream append(byte[] content, InputStream inPdf) throws IOException, DocumentException {

  ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16000);
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inPdf);
  PdfAStamper stamper = new PdfAStamper(reader, result, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3B);

  stamper.createXmpMetadata();

  // Creating PDF/A-3 compliant attachment.
  PdfDictionary embeddedFileParams = new PdfDictionary();
  embeddedFileParams.put(PARAMS, new PdfName(ZF_NAME));
  embeddedFileParams.put(MODDATE, new PdfDate());
  PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(stamper.getWriter(), null,ZF_NAME, content , "text/xml", embeddedFileParams,0);
  fs.put(AFRELATIONSHIP, Alternative);
  stamper.addFileAttachment("file description",fs);

  stamper.close();
  reader.close();
  return result;
}
```

Here is the Stacktrace of the error.

```
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: EF key of the file specification dictionary for an embedded file shall contain dictionary with valid F key.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfA3Checker.checkFileSpec(PdfA3Checker.java:95)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAChecker.checkPdfAConformance(PdfAChecker.java:198)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAConformanceImp.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfAConformanceImp.java:70)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3380)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3376)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.toPdf(PdfFileSpecification.java:309)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(PdfIndirectObject.java:157)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.write(PdfWriter.java:424)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:402)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:381)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:334)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:819)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.getReference(PdfFileSpecification.java:256)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addFileAttachment(PdfDocument.java:2253)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addFileAttachment(PdfWriter.java:1714)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper.addFileAttachment(PdfStamper.java:497)
```

Now when I try to analyze the Stacktrace and take a look at`PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded`
I see that an EF is created with an F and UF entry.

Looking inside `PdfA3Checker` I see that line `PdfDictionary embeddedFile = getDirectDictionary(dict.get(PdfName.F));` is not a directory but a strem.

```
if (fileSpec.contains(PdfName.EF)) {
    PdfDictionary dict = getDirectDictionary(fileSpec.get(PdfName.EF));
    if (dict == null || !dict.contains(PdfName.F)) {
        throw new PdfAConformanceException(obj1, MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage("ef.key.of.file.specification.dictionary.shall.contain.dictionary.with.valid.f.key"));
    }

    PdfDictionary embeddedFile = getDirectDictionary(dict.get(PdfName.F));
    if (embeddedFile == null) {
        throw new PdfAConformanceException(obj1, MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage("ef.key.of.file.specification.dictionary.shall.contain.dictionary.with.valid.f.key"));
    }

    checkEmbeddedFile(embeddedFile);
}
```

Is this a bug in iText or am I missing something? By the way I am using iText 5.4.5.

**Update 1**

As suggested by Bruno an [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) the 4.5.6-Snapshot should contains the fix. I tried my Test case [Gist link to full test case](https://gist.github.com/Vad1mo/b1759fc3ba234d79009e) against the current trunk. But the result was the same error.

Comment: There is am issue in iText 5.4.5 concerning pdf/a-3 file embedding. Read e.g. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018428/creating-pdf-a-3-embedded-file-shall-contain-valid-params-key/21020431#21020431).

Comment: I read the [answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018428/creating-pdf-a-3-embedded-file-shall-contain-valid-params-key/21020431#21020431) While it seems similar because we face the same error I think that the cause is a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've indeed hit a bug in iText 5.4.5. This bug was reported here: [Creating PDF/A-3: Embedded file shall contain valid Params key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018428/creating-pdf-a-3-embedded-file-shall-contain-valid-params-key)
It was fixed in the SVN version of iText. We're preparing the next version of iText (due this week).

Comment: Bruno, I just tried itext 5.4.6-Snapshot and my Tescae still has the same error. See my Updated Question for more details.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie The OP circumvented the bug from the referred-to [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018428/creating-pdf-a-3-embedded-file-shall-contain-valid-params-key) by making use of a byte[] instead of a file. His issue is triggered in a slightly different conformance test.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie The issue is due to different caching by `PdfAWriter` (which caches) and `PdfAStamper` (which doesn't) in the `PdfAChecker` object cache. Thus, the check fails in case of stamped attachments. See my answer.

Comment: We'll try to fix this ASAP

Comment: New snapshot is working fine. When can we expect the release?

Comment: It's scheduled for Friday.

Answer (score 3):

You ran into a bug very similar to the one focused in [Creating PDF/A-3: Embedded file shall contain valid Params key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018428/creating-pdf-a-3-embedded-file-shall-contain-valid-params-key):

The problem (as you found out) is in this code

```
PdfDictionary embeddedFile = getDirectDictionary(dict.get(PdfName.F));
if (embeddedFile == null) {
    throw new PdfAConformanceException(obj1, MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage("ef.key.of.file.specification.dictionary.shall.contain.dictionary.with.valid.f.key"));
}
```

in PdfA3Checker.checkFileSpec(PdfWriter, int, Object); even though `dict` contains a stream named **F**, `getDirectDictionary(dict.get(PdfName.F))` does not return it. The reason is not, though, that a dictionary is sought here (a stream essentially is a dictionary with some additions), but it is an issue in `PdfAChecker.getDirectObject` which is called by `PdfAChecker.getDirectDictionary`:

```
protected PdfObject getDirectObject(PdfObject obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    //use counter to prevent indirect reference cycling
    int count = 0;
    while (obj.type() == 0) {
        PdfObject tmp = cachedObjects.get(new RefKey((PdfIndirectReference)obj));
        if (tmp == null)
            break;
        obj = tmp;
        //10 - is max allowed reference chain
        if (count++ > 10)
            break;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

This method only looks for cached objects (i.e. in `cachedObjects`) but in your case (and a test of mine, too) this stream has already been written to file and is not in cache anymore resulting in a `null` returned... correction, cf the PPS: it has been written but it has **not been cached** to begin with.

PS: PDF/A-3 conform file attachments work if added during PDF creation (using a `PdfAWriter`), but not if added during PDF manipulation (using a `PdfAStamper`); maybe the caching is different in these use cases.

PPS: Indeed there is a difference: `PdfAWriter` overrides the `addToBody` overloads by adding the added objects to a cache. `PdfAStamperImp` does not do so and furthermore is derived from `PdfStamperImp` and `PdfWriter`, not from `PdfAWriter`.